# Webpack requires file extension for react components

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use Webpack in my React project using VS Code and running into an issue because webpack is now requiring the file extensions for my components.

For example, webpack tells me that it's unable to resolve the following component:

```
import MyComponent from '../components/Component123';
```

If I change it to the following by adding the file extension, it works fine:

```
import MyComponent from '../components/Component123.jsx';
```

I've never had this before and it's not even the conventional norm. What's causing this and how do I fix it?

BTW, my webpack version is 2.6.1.

Comment: Could you add your webpack config? Could be that adding `jsx` to your resolve extensions fixes this: `extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],`.

Comment: Yes, I actually just tried it and it resolved the problem. I don't remember ever adding the resolve section in my `webpack.config.js` file. I wonder if this is now required in webpack version 2.

Comment: Extensions have always been required in Webpack, so webpack knows what files to look for when you ask for a file without ext